# Hibernate / JPA use provided Ids for saving

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is there a simple to way to use provided Ids for entities when saving them into empty database?

When using `EntityManager.persist(...)` call it fails cause it thinks the entity is detached (as it has an Id). I don't want to use `EntityManager.merge(...)` for performance reasons (it fires an additional select for every entity).

I tried different ways, e.g. providing `ForeignGenerator`, but Ids are nulled then before saving and NPE is fired.

I also tried providing Hibernate `Interceptor` and overriding its `isTransient()` to always return `true`, but then I can't cascade save properly (or at least I have to maintain a cache of already persisted entities by myself).

I think there should be a simple way to do that, but can't find any.

**Updated:** added entity mappings

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "admNr")
public class Adm implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ADM_NR", nullable = false)
    private String admNr;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "adm", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Kunde> kundeList = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "kundeNr")
public class Kunde implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Kunde_Nr", nullable = false)
    private String kundeNr;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ADM_Nr", referencedColumnName = "ADM_NR")
    private Adm adm;

}
```

**Updated:** provided additional info

I don't create entities manually, they are created as a part of data migration routine, and bidirectional relations are properly set in the process, so this is not possible that `kunde.getAdm()` will ever be null. Anyway, I tried removing `nullable = false` from `Kunde.adm` but the result was the same.

I did set up cascades to be able to save the entire graph using just `em.persist(adm)` as I didn't want to visit every child and persist it explicitly (the model I provided is a simplified one, actually there are more nesting levels in it).

`String` PKs are some legacy stuff I can't get rid of unfortunately.

The error I get when persisting the graph (calling `em.persist(adm)`) is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : de.apollon.dmx.workflow.processing.sqlite.adm.domain.Kunde.adm -> de.apollon.dmx.workflow.processing.sqlite.adm.domain.Adm
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:797) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:768) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:305) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at de.apollon.dmx.workflow.processing.sqlite.adm.service.SqliteAdmPackageService.storeAdmPackage(SqliteAdmPackageService.java:60) ~[classes/:na]
    at de.apollon.dmx.workflow.processing.sqlite.adm.service.SqliteAdmPackageService.createAdmPackageResource(SqliteAdmPackageService.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at de.apollon.dmx.workflow.processing.sqlite.adm.service.SqliteAdmPackageService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6a54d95.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at de.apollon.dmx.workflow.processing.sqlite.adm.service.SqliteAdmPackageService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5ba50508.createAdmPackageResource(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at de.apollon.dmx.workflow.processing.service.AdmPackageService.createAdmPackage(AdmPackageService.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
    at de.apollon.dmx.workflow.processing.service.ProcessingService.processAdmPackage(ProcessingService.java:111) [classes/:na]
    at de.apollon.dmx.workflow.processing.service.ProcessingService.runTest(ProcessingService.java:58) [classes/:na]
    at de.apollon.dmx.workflow.Application.lambda$applicationRunner$0(Application.java:31) [classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset$$$capture(FutureTask.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : de.apollon.dmx.workflow.processing.sqlite.adm.domain.Kunde.adm -> de.apollon.dmx.workflow.processing.sqlite.adm.domain.Adm
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions.checkNoUnresolvedActionsAfterOperation(UnresolvedEntityInsertActions.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.checkNoUnresolvedActionsAfterOperation(ActionQueue.java:432) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkNoUnresolvedActionsAfterOperation(SessionImpl.java:631) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:794) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Comment: can you provide the mapping for your entity?

Comment: That is the way to do it. You don't need nullable = false because it is an Id.

Comment: Are the columns with the Id annotations primary key columns in the database? Does the database generate a value for that column if you insert directly?

Comment: @K.Nicholas could you pls tell which way exactly do you mean there?

Comment: @JohnCamerin no these Ids actually hold business value and can't be generated by the database.

Comment: You will need to provided an idgenerator to hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the models were created with ModelMapper, and it provided different instances of the same entity at two sides of the relationship.

```
Adm (AdmNr="1234", Java instance @1234)
  .kundeList
  -> Kunde (KundeNr="2345", Java instance @2345)
    .adm
    -> Adm (AdmNr="1234", Java instance @4444) <- should be @1234
```

That lead to Hibernate thinking the Adm entity is transient and throwing an exception, as there is no cascade from Kunde to Adm.

Solved with adjusting ModelMapper so it provided the same instance for one PK.

Answer (score 1):

You have a chicken and egg problem. One the one hand you have `Adm` with a `Kunde` Set and `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`. With cascade you are asking the `Adm` entity to save the `Kunde` relation for you without having to set the `Adm` field of the `Kunde`. So, I assume you are trying to save them both without doing so.

```
    Adm adm = new Adm();
    adm.setAdmNr("NO1");
    Kunde kunde = new Kunde();
    kunde.setKundeNr("NO1");
    adm.getKundeList().add(kunde);
    em.persist(adm);
```

On the other hand you have annotated the `Kunde` field with `optional = false` saying that it is impermissible to not set the `Adm` field of `Kunde`, which the above code doesn't do. Therefore it gives you a not-null error. You should have provided (part of) your stacktrace in your question.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : model.Kunde.adm

So, to fix either remove the not null condition or set the `Adm` property of `Kunde`

```
    Adm adm = new Adm();
    adm.setAdmNr("NO1");
    Kunde kunde = new Kunde();
    kunde.setKundeNr("NO1");
    kunde.setAdm(adm);
    adm.getKundeList().add(kunde);
    em.persist(adm);
```

Also, as I said above, you don't need `nullable = false` on the primary keys because every primary key field is created with an unique index that prohibits nulls.

As a side note it is not a good idea to create a `HashSet` for the `kundeList` with every new `Adm` instance. You have a bidirectional mapping owned by the `Kunde` entity but that ownership is overridden by the `cascade` setting for a subset of operations. Assuming you are going to be doing more queries than updates the new HashSet will always be thrown out for the JPA managed list when you query. The `cascade` setting does not apply to queries so you won't be getting a filled out `kundeList` unless your query specifically asks for it and the Hashset will be replaced with an empty JPA managed list anyway. The above working code works fine if you simply add a `em.persist(Kunde)` to it and remove the `cascade` setting. For all these reasons and probably more I think it is preferable to manage the relationship specifically yourself and use the `kundeList` as a query only field for which it works best.

Finally, it's a really bad idea to use Strings as primary keys.

Comment: I have updated the original question with some more info. I also found out what the problem was, added it as an answer.

Comment: Added it in an answer.